# Java: formato científico al convertir String a Double

Tags: java, formato, double

Saludos!!!

Tengo una clase que entre otros atributos, tiene uno llamado "Valor" definido como de tipo Double.
Al recuperar desde la base de datos este valor: 286578432.33 al asignarlo al atributo "Valor"  no lo almacena de esa forma, sino como 2.8657843233E8 ( notación científica )
Con valores como 48573.44  no tengo problemas. Al parecer a partir de ciertos valores, el atributo Double lo guarda con notación científica.
Al final, necesito que ese atributo guarde el valor sin notación científica ( 286578432.33 )

Alguna sugerencia al respecto?

Gracias de antemano !!!!

```
    public class pruebaStrDbl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deuda deuda = new Deuda();
        Number number = null;
        NumberFormat _format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        try {
            String valor = "268578081.53";
             number = _format.parse(valor.toString());
            deuda.setDeudaVencida(  Double.parseDouble(  number.toString() ) );
            System.out.println(deuda.deudaVencida);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código que usas para transformar de un tipo a otro? Creo que tienes un concepto equivocado de cómo funciona el tipo `double`

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el código ahí, no en un comentario

Answer (score 1):

La veerdad, mera verdad, jamas habia trabajado con números asi tan grandes y tu caso me desperto curiosidad.

Por suerte, investigando por ahi ([aqui](https://gonzasilve.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/conversion-de-numero-en-notacion-cientifica-a-notacion-normal/) concretamente) se puede lograr eso que deseas gracias a la clase **DecimalFormat**. Aqui su uso con tu situacion:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 *
 * @author Phillips
 */
public class Sample {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   double var = 286578432.33;
   System.out.println(convertir(var));
}

public static String convertir(double val){
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    DecimalFormat num = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
    return num.format(val);
}

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora... si el tema es que lo quieres guardar asi tal cual dentro de una variable double... creo que es inevitable que JAVA lo guarde como notacion.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Publico cambios por el comentario de **J.barrio** (mis creditos para el). Puedes hacer uso de la clase [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B). Por ejemplo, sin tener que recurrir al metodo escrito arriba, simplemente tendria que hacer algo asi:

```
public class Sample {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   double var = 286578432.33;       
   System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(var));
}

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso viendo tu codigo: `BigDecimal.valueOf(deuda.deudaVencida)`

Comment: Y el tipo [BigDecimal] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) de Java? Puede ser una opción?

Comment: @j.barrio Toda la razón J.barrio......

Comment: Gracias!!! estamos revisando esta alternativa. Con lo que nos resulte, les comento.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sample {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   double var = 286578432.33;       
   System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(var));
}
}
```

yo use esta solución , pero tengo el problema que cuando envió este valor 286578432.30 me imprime 286578432.3 me quita el cero al final.

Answer (score 0):

por si alguien aun busca como hacerlo, creo que esta manera es simple de formatear la salida a string sin la notacion cientifica:

```
double var = 286578432.33; 
String.format("%.2f",deuda.deudaVencida);
```

La salida seria:

286578432.30